# What is the lore behind why soul coins have the symbol of Bhaal on them?

Tags: dnd-5e, lore, forgotten-realms, soul, art

I am struggling to find an image of both sides of a Soul Coin (Baator’s currency), but everywhere I've looked, I've only found only one side bearing a letter and the other side depicting a skull with blood droplets flying around it.

But it is the symbol of Bhaal. Why does it appear on Baator’s currency?

Am I correct about how soul coins look? What images appear on the sides of a soul coin, and why?

Comment: I've edited the question to try and clarify what you're asking. Please check to make sure it still matches your intent.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

### We only get one side of the soul coin in official material

As far as I know, the only depiction of the soul coin in official D&D 5e material appears in *Baldur's Gate: Descent into Avernus* in [Appendix C](https://www.dndbeyond.com/sources/bgdia/magic-items#SoulCoin):

[image]

The depictions of the other side of the coin appear to originate from [this tweet](https://twitter.com/jimzub/status/1129574418798108672) from Jim Zub, a writer of multiple D&D comics, who claims to have contributed to the design of the soul coin and its addition to the adventure module.

[image]

As far as I can tell, the skull and blood droplets side of the coin never appeared in the book or any other official source.

In terms of a connection to Bhaal, there is nothing in the lore about Bhaal having anything to do with *soul coins*, or really the Nine Hells in general in any major capacity.

Comment: The blood and logo come from the [Baldur's Gate video game](https://vignette.wikia.nocookie.net/baldursgategame/images/2/24/Bgee_logo.png/revision/latest?cb=20170118053959). Since this is for _"**Baldur's Gate**: Descent into Avernus"_, they likely just kept the logo for nostalgia.